# How do you test Wicket TextFields for read-only?

Tags: java, unit-testing, wicket, readonly, wicket-tester

I want to test that my Wicket `TextField` is set to `readonly`. I have set up my `WicketTester` but that just supports `assertDisabled()` which is useless and fails in my case.

I already tried `tester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage(compName).getString("readonly")` and 
`tester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage(compName).getMarkupAttributes().get("readonly")` which both sounded somewhat promising to me but failed to deliver.

Comment: How did you set your TextFields to disabled?

Comment: textFieldInstance.add(new AttributeModifier(READONLY, READONLY))

Comment: I think this is the sort of thing that is best tested with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `WicketTester` doesn't make it easy to do this very directly, but ...

Since `AttributeModifier` is a behavior, you can call

```
Component component = tester.getComponentFromLastRenderedPage("path");
List<IBehavior> behaviors = component.getBehaviors();
```

and pull the `AttributeModifier` instances from the list (using `instanceof`  or `isAssignableFrom` checks).  Then after some reflection to make things accessible, you can check whether there's one that matches your expected `AttributeModifier`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solvable by:

```
TagTester ttest = tester.getTagByWicketId(compName);
assertNotNull(ttest.getAttribute(READONLY));
```

or something very similar. I can't test this right now, so I can't be more specific.
For more details check the JavaDocs of [TagTester](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/1.5.x/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/TagTester.html)